# Please help me with radio button action in lightning component::

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, action, radio-button

I am unable to trigger the action for radio button in lightning component.

Here is the code for the radio button:

```
<aura:attribute name="opportunities" type="Opportunity[]" />
<aura:attribute name="page" type="integer"/>
<aura:attribute name="pages" type="integer"/>
<aura:attribute name="total" type="integer"/>
<aura:attribute name="searchKey" type="String" default=""/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" /> 
<aura:handler event="c:SearchBarEvent" action="{!c.searchKeyFunction}"/>
<aura:handler event="c:PageChange" action="{!c.pageChange}"/>
<div class="slds-grid slds-grid--align-spread">
    <c:SearchBarCmpt />

    <fieldset class="slds-form-element">
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <label class="slds-radio">
            <input type="radio" name="options" onClick="{!myOpps}"/>
            <span class="slds-radio--faux"></span>
            <span class="slds-form-element__label">My Opportunities</span>
            </label>
            <label class="slds-radio">    
            <input type="radio" name="options"/>
            <span class="slds-radio--faux"></span>
            <span class="slds-form-element__label">All Oportunities</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="slds-form-element">
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <label class="slds-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="checkbox-01" />
            <span class="slds-checkbox--faux"></span>
            <span class="slds-form-element__label">Open Opportunities</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral">New Opportunity</button>
    </div>

</div>
<table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--striped">
    <thead>
        <tr class="slds-text-heading--label">
            <th width="20%"><span class="slds-truncate"><strong>Owner</strong></span></th>
            <th width="35%" scope="col"><span class="slds-truncate"><strong>Name</strong></span></th>
            <th width="10%" scope="col"><span class="slds-truncate"><strong>CloseDate</strong></span></th>
            <th width="15%" scope="col"><span class="slds-truncate"><strong>Stage</strong></span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    </table>

    <aura:iteration items="{!v.opportunities}" var="opportunities">
       <c:AccOppListItem opportunities="{!opportunities}"/>  
    </aura:iteration>


<c:Paginator page="{!v.page}" pages="{!v.pages}" total="{!v.total}"/>
```

In the action of radio I am calling controller function called myopps.

```
myOpps: function(component, event, helper) {    
    var page = 1;
    helper.getMyOpps(component,event, page);
}
```

helper

```
({
  getOpps: function(component, event, page) {
    page = page || 1;
    var action = component.get("c.findByPage");
    action.setParams({
        "pageNumber": page
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        var result = a.getReturnValue();
        component.set("v.opportunities", result.entries);
        component.set("v.page", result.page);
        component.set("v.total", result.total);
        component.set("v.pages", Math.ceil(result.total/result.pageSize));
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

getMyOpps: function(component, event, page) {
    page = page || 1;
    var action = component.get("c.getMyOpps");
    action.setParams({
        "pageNumber": page
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        var result = a.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.opportunities", result.entries);
            component.set("v.page", result.page);
            component.set("v.total", result.total);
            component.set("v.pages", Math.ceil(result.total/result.pageSize));           
            $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();

    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  }   
})
```

This helper will call the apex controller method.

Apex controller method:

```
public class AccOppRLController {

  @AuraEnabled
  public static PagedResult getMyOpps(Decimal pageNumber) {
    Integer pageSize = 5;
    //String name = '%' + searchKey + '%';
    Integer offset = ((Integer)pageNumber - 1) * pageSize;
    system.debug('offset==='+offset+'  pageNumber===='+pageNumber);
    PagedResult r =  new PagedResult();
    r.pageSize = pageSize;
    r.page = (Integer) pageNumber;
    r.total = [SELECT Count() FROM Opportunity];
    r.entries = [SELECT Id, name, Owner.Name, CloseDate, StageName FROM Opportunity where Owner.Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT :pageSize OFFSET :offset];
    system.debug('my opps===='+ r.entries);
    return r;
  }
}
```

I dont understand where I am wrong.

Comment: Could you share your component code also ? @ Srinivas

Comment: @Srinivas your question is too vague, you have not described what exactly is not working and what you have tried to do. You just provided a lot of code and said it's not working. In addition, an answer was provided.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tag named [**ui:inputRadio**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputRadio.htm) which can be used for radio buttons.

Your component part can be changed to following code:-

```
<fieldset class="slds-form-element">
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
        <ui:inputRadio label="My Opportunities" change="{!c.myOpps}"/>
        <ui:inputRadio label="All Oportunities"/>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Also please note that whenever you call a method from component, use **{!c.functionName}**.

Comment: Thanks for response, can you let me know How to refresh the component like If you take a look the component , it includes a component called "c:Paginator" . I need to refresh that component when the user clicked on My Opportunities.

Comment: @Srinivas you can use  force:refreshView event. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_refreshView.htm . If this solves your issue, please mark it as the best answer.

Comment: This is what I have updated in the helper class as per your suggestion::
action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
  var state= a.getState();
   var result = a.getReturnValue();
  component.set("v.opportunities", result.entries);
 component.set("v.page", result.page);
 component.set("v.total", result.total);
    component.set("v.pages", Math.ceil(result.total/result.pageSize));
   if(state === 'SUCCESS')
   {                
    $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
  }
I got an error like:Error in $A.getCallback() [TypeError: $A.get(...) is undefined]Failing descriptor

Comment: @Srinivas Could you please the full code in helper ?

Comment: I have edited helper code in the main question. please take a look and help me

Comment: @Srinivas On doing what action, you are getting this error ?

Comment: @Srinivas I think you haven't noticed the change in  component I mentioned in my answer. Please have a look at using  ui:inputRadio in the component.

Comment: No, I have edited component in my org..not here actually.I am getting error exactly at $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();

Comment: @Srinivas Its working fine for me. I am not facing any issue.

Comment: I have shared code with you, tell me where can I go wrong.